# General questions about Django and DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've made a project using Django and Bootstrap (I plan to use React for the frontend). Then I started building REST API with DRF and it seems that my DRF views are pretty similar (if not duplicative) to my original Django views such as DetailView, UpdateView and etc.
Now I wonder if I can keep my old views or should I completely replace them with DRF ones? Or should I use DRF views for CRUD and keep particular Django views?
And another qusetion: am I right that when working with Django and DRF Django becomes just an ORM provider also responsible for business logic, authentication and some other features?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django is a fullstack web development framework. Here you can progress in different ways. You can use Django and ReactJS without having to develop any RestAPI. It depends on how you approach it with ReactJs.

Do you want to develop the frontend entirely with ReactJS? If so, you can develop your backend directly using DRF and consume APIs on the frontend only with React.

While developing a full stack with Core Django, if you want to make the Frontend dynamic, you can use Django and DRF together, or you can develop APIs without using DRF.

You can use DRF and Core Django together for different scenarios, or you may only need one of them. It depends on you and your project.

**Edit for second question:**

Django Rest Framework requires Django. Also, with Django you can do everything DRF does. By writing more code of course. This process provides many conveniences with DRF; like authentication modules, json serializers..